# Catalan number but with "bad moves"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Im struggling to solve this question (The context is Catalan numbers):
With only "up" and "right" moves from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$,
We'll call the "up" moves above the $y=x$, "Bad Moves".

Let $0 \leq k \leq n-1$,

Prove that the number of routes with (k) Bad Moves = the number of routes with (k+1) Bad Moves.

Comment: See the second proof in the [Wikipedia article on Catalan numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: This is the *Chung-Feller theorem*.

Comment: It’s really the third proof in the Wikipedia article, I think. It seems rather difficult, for an exercise, to expect you to discover this clever argument.